# Cant connect to RJDBC using Rscript on .R file

Tags: r, jdbc

Im trying to run an R script where im trying to connect to Amazon Redshift using RJDBC. 
This is my code to connect to Redshift.

```
drv<-JDBC("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver","/home/soumyadeep/Downloads/RedshiftJDBC42-1.1.17.1017.jar") 
con<-dbConnect(drv,"jdbc:redshift://170.31.0.129:5439/dev","query","5vIU")
Traffic_Over <- gsub('[\r\n\t]','',paste(readLines("Queries_Marketing/Traffic.sql"), collapse = " ")) 
Traffic_Overall<-dbGetQuery(con,Traffic_Over)
```

When I run the script on the Linux Terminal I counter the following error.

```
Loading required package: methods
Loading required package: DBI

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found
Calls: JDBC -> is.jnull -> .jfindClass
Execution halted
```

Comment: This is to set up the command.

Comment: drv<-JDBC("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver","/home/soumyadeep/Downloads/RedshiftJDBC42-1.1.17.1017.jar")

con<-dbConnect(drv,"jdbc:redshift://172.31.0.139:5439/dev","query","5kl2GvIU")

Comment: Lastly when I run the code on Rstudio, it works fine, just when I run on the terminal I face the issue. Thank You so Much.